# Wordpress Walker class for wp_list_pages

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm using wp_list_pages to create a nav of the pages in my site.

Some pages have a chilren so I need a dropdown menu in the nav to show the child pages.

I'm using bootstrap to create the dropdown menus.

To use bootstrap I need to add class names to the li, a and ul containing the child pages

I think the best way to add these classes is using a custom walker class.

How do I write this custom class to add the classes I need.

The outputed html

```
    <ul class="">
        <li class="page_item page-item-6 current_page_item"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-6 current_page_item"><a href="/">Profile</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-8 page_item_has_children">
            <a href="">Products &#038; Services</a>
            <ul class='children'>
                <li class="page_item page-item-17"><a href="">Buying</a></li>
                <li class="page_item page-item-19"><a href="">Selling</a></li>
                <li class="page_item page-item-23"><a href="">Managing</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

The html I need

```
    <ul class="">
        <li class="page_item page-item-6 current_page_item"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-6 current_page_item"><a href="/">Profile</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-8 page_item_has_children dropdown">
            <a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Products &#038; Services</a>
            <ul class='children dropdown-menu'>
                <li class="page_item page-item-17"><a href="">Buying</a></li>
                <li class="page_item page-item-19"><a href="">Selling</a></li>
                <li class="page_item page-item-23"><a href="">Managing</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery:

```
$(".page_item_has_children").each(function() {
  $(this).addClass("dropdown");
});

$("li.page_item_has_children > a").each(function() {
  $(this).addClass("dropdown-toggle");
  $(this).attr( "data-toggle", "dropdown" );
  $(this).next().addClass("dropdown-menu");
});
```

**[Working Example](http://jsbin.com/taxeqihu/2)**

Comment: I thought about this but the jquery won't load until the page has loaded so you could get a flash of the nag unstyled before the page fully loads, I would prefer to do it server side.